# bash script check existing file before running script

Tags: bash, nagios

As I am new to bash scripting (vbs is more my stuff), I can't get this to run. Probably very simple for y'all:

I have a bash script on the C-system disk that is starting a NagWin (nagios for windows) plugin, but in that script I want to start off with a line of code that does a file existence checking on the D-drive in a certain folder.

If this file is there, it just can echo a message and exit, 
else if this is not there it should continue with the script on the C-drive

The other part of the script runs well only it does not do any checking, probably because something is wrong with the jumping to d drive and c drive or something

Already thanks

Comment: Please post your code, we can't help you without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ -f D:/file/on/d/drive ]
then C:/script/on/c/drive
else echo "Did not find file D:/file/on/d/drive" 1>&2
fi
```

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot my double colon after the drive-path, that is why it was not working. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

```
if test -f '/path/to/file'; then
  #Do your work
else
  echo 'File not found, exiting.'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the presence of a file in different ways in bash:

1)

```
if [ -f "/path/to/file" ]; then echo "OK"; else echo "KO"; fi
```

2)

```
[ -f "/path/to/file" ] && echo "OK"
```

3)

```
[ -f "/path/to/file" ] || echo "KO"
```

4)

```
if test -f "/path/to/file"; then echo "OK"; else echo "KO"; fi
```